# C++ Primer 5th Edition Chapter 16.5 Class-Template Specializations

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, errata

I think the book contains an error on page 711:

> In § 16.2.3 (p. 684) we introduced the library `remove_reference`
> type. That template works through a series of specializations:
>
> ```
> // original, most general template
> template <class T> struct remove_reference {
>     typedef T type;
> };
> // partial specializations that will be used fore lvalue and rvalue references
> template <class T> struct remove_reference<T&> // lvalue references
>     typedef T type;
> };
> template <class T> struct remove_reference<T&&> // rvalue references
>     typedef T type;
> };
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> int i;
> // declyptype(42) is int, used the original template
> remove_reference<decltype(42)>::type a;
> // decltype(i) is int&, uses first(T&) partial specialization
> remove_reference<decltype(i)>::type b;
> // delctype(std::move(i)) is int&&, uses second (i.e., T&&) partial specialization
> remove_reference<decltype(std::move(i))>::type c;
> ```
>
> All three variables, `a`,`b`,and `c`, have type `int`.

I think `decltype(i)` yields a plain `int` and not `int&` therefore the most general template is used actually in case of `b`. For plain variable types <sup>[1]</sup> the `decltype` type specifier yields plain types and for other expressions which can be used as `lvalue` the it will yield and `lvalue reference`.

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> struct blubb {
    typedef T type;
    void print() { cout << "plain argument type\n"; }
};

template <typename T> struct blubb<T&> {
    typedef T type;
    void print() { cout << "lvalue reference type\n"; }
};

template <typename T> struct blubb<T&&> {
    typedef T type;
    void print() { cout << "rvalue reference type\n"; }
};

int main() {
    int i = 0;

    blubb<decltype(42)> plain;
    plain.print();
    blubb<decltype(i)> lvalue_ref; // actually not!
    lvalue_ref.print();
    
    int* pi = &i;
    blubb<decltype(*pi)> lvalue_ref2; // expression which can be on the left hand side
    lvalue_ref2.print();

    blubb<decltype(std::move(i))> rvalue_ref;
    rvalue_ref.print();

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile and Run**

```
g++ -o types types.cpp -Wall -pedantic -g && ./types
plain argument type
plain argument type
lvalue reference type
rvalue reference type
```

Please tell me if I'm right or wrong and explain if appropriate.
Thank you

<sup>[1]</sup> Probably the correct term is `id-expression`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for unparenthesized id-expression, [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) yields the type of entity named by the id-expression, then `decltype(i)` yields the type `int`.

> 1. If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access expression, then `decltype` yields the type of the entity named by this expression.

On the other hand, `decltype((i))` yields the type `int&`; `(i)` is treated as an lvalue expression.

> 2. If the argument is any other expression of type `T`, and
>    b) if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields `T&`;

> Note that if the name of an object is parenthesized, it is treated as an ordinary lvalue expression, thus `decltype(x)` and `decltype((x))` are often different types.